# Filter file types from list to NOT show certain file types

Tags: filter

I have a document library list.
Lots files, and a handful of file types.
I know how to force a filter via the URL. Saw docx file.
But right now, I have a need to show all files except docx, pptx, xlsx. 
So things like pdfs, rar, zips, etc... should show.

Any thoughts on this kind of filter and how to accomplish it? Right now, I have a crazy javascript planned out, but feel it's too messy.

Answer (score 5):

Using following  CAML `Where` clause

```
<Where>
   <And>
      <And>
         <Neq><FieldRef Name="DocIcon"/><Value Type="Computed">docx</Value></Neq>
         <Neq><FieldRef Name="DocIcon"/><Value Type="Computed">pptx</Value></Neq>
      </And>
      <Neq><FieldRef Name="DocIcon"/><Value Type="Computed">xlsx</Value></Neq>
   </And>
</Where>
```

file types `docx`, `pptx` and `xslx` will be excluded. [DocIcon column](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spbuiltinfieldid.docicon.aspx) (Display Name `Type`) is used to determine file type.

The same List View filter configured in View settings page is shown below

[image]