# Selecting only PowerPoint files in a CAML query

Tags: document-library, csom, caml-query, caml, file

I am trying to select all PowerPoint files in a list. How do I do that? Up until now I used this:

```
class UsedIn
{
private static NetworkCredential credential = new NetworkCredential("login", "pwd", "domain");

static String filename = "Engineering_Weekly_Report.pptx";

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    try
    {
        // Creating the Clientcontext
        ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext("https://sharepoint.adress.com/subfolder/");
        clientContext.Credentials = credential;
        Web oWebsite = clientContext.Web;

        // Collect all lists from Sharepoint.
        ListCollection collList = oWebsite.Lists;
        clientContext.Load(collList);
        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
        Console.WriteLine("Connected to Sharepoint.");

        // Getting the Presentation.
        Console.WriteLine("Working on " + filename + "..");
        Guid id = new Guid("CC37C3F4-97D0-4181-87A3-6143DD45004F"); // List ID for the Slide Library.
        List sharedDocumentsList = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetById(id);
        CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery();

        camlQuery.ViewXml = "<View Scope = 'RecursiveAll'></View>";
        ListItemCollection listItems = sharedDocumentsList.GetItems(camlQuery);
        clientContext.Credentials = credential;
        clientContext.Load(sharedDocumentsList);
        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

        clientContext.Credentials = credential;
        clientContext.Load(listItems);
        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
        Console.WriteLine("Opened Document.");

        foreach (var item in listItems)
        {
            clientContext.Credentials = credential;
            FileInformation fileInformation = ClientOM.File.OpenBinaryDirect(clientContext, (string)item["FileRef"]);

            using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                PresentationDocument ppt = PresentationDocument.Open(memoryStream, true);
                Console.WriteLine("Found the Document.");
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Done.");
        Console.Read();
    }

    catch (Exception ex) when (ex is ServerException || ex is InvalidCastException || ex is OpenXmlPackageException || ex is WebException)
    {

    }
}
```

But now I have to work with a list that is not clean and has some pdfs in it. Is there a way to only select `.pptx` with CAML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='FileExtension'><Value Type='text'>pptx</Value></FieldRef></Eq></Where>
```

Answer (score 2):

You may use `DocIcon` to determine the type of file in your CAML Query

```
<Eq><FieldRef Name="DocIcon"/><Value Type="Computed">pptx</Value></Eq>
```

Source: [Filter file types from list to NOT show certain file types](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/91126/filter-file-types-from-list-to-not-show-certain-file-types)

Comment: I'm not sure I'd rely on the `DocIcon` value for this since the `FileExtension` is more direct and intent is readable.

Comment: Agree, but just another way, if needed.

Comment: FileExtension is not working for me in SP 2016 while DocIcon does work.