# Getting only powerpoint files via CAML query

Tags: development, caml

This is the query I use to get only Powerpoint files from a list:

```
        Guid id = new Guid(reportLibrary); // ID for the Report library. Needs to be configured at the beginning of the class.
        List sharedDocumentsList = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetById(id);
        CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
        camlQuery.ViewXml = "<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='FileExtension'><Value Type='text'>ppt</Value></FieldRef></Eq></Where>";
        ListItemCollection listItems = sharedDocumentsList.GetItems(camlQuery);
        clientContext.Load(sharedDocumentsList);
        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

I got the query from this question: [Selecting only PowerPoint files in a CAML query](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/190351/selecting-only-powerpoint-files-in-a-caml-query)
Sadly, the query does not do what I would expect. It still returns all the files in the list, which results in a crash further down, since the programm I wrote only expects Powerpoint files. Am I doing something wrong? Do I have to execute the query differently?

Comment: You are missing `<View><Query>` around your CAML (also add `</Query></View>` at the end

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `<View>` and `<Query>` tags in ViewXml. Your `ViewXml` will be like:

```
camlQuery.ViewXml = "<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='FileExtension'><Value Type='Text'>ppt</Value></FieldRef></Eq></Where><Query><View>";
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use `DocIcon` to filter results, make sure to support both **ppt** and **pptx** file formats, and use some value for **RowLimit**.

```
<View>
 <Query>
   <Where>
      <Or>
         <Eq>
            <FieldRef Name='DocIcon' />
            <Value Type='Computed'>pptx</Value>
         </Eq>
         <Eq>
            <FieldRef Name='DocIcon' />
            <Value Type='Computed'>ppt</Value>
         </Eq>
      </Or>
   </Where>
 </Query>
 <RowLimit>2000</RowLimit>
</View>
```

See also:

[How to: Retrieve List Items](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee534956%28v=office.14%29.aspx)