# SharePoint CAML: Search Subfolder and PDF File Type

Tags: sharepoint-online, caml, highlighted-content-web-part

In a Highligthed Content web part, I want only PDF files to display from a certain document library's subfolder. I have the following CAML - it filters all documents from the indicated subfolder (showing all file types). How can I further filter to only show PDF files from this subfolder?

```
<View Scope='RecursiveAll'>
<Query>
    <Where>
         <Contains>
         <FieldRef Name='FileDirRef'/><Value Type='Lookup'>SUBFOLDERNAME</Value>
      </Contains>
    </Where>
</Query>
</View>
```

Comment: Try adding additional filter based on File Type column: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/190351/selecting-only-powerpoint-files-in-a-caml-query. Let me know if this works for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use CAML query like this:

```
<View Scope='RecursiveAll'>
    <Query>
        <Where>
            <And>
                <Contains><FieldRef Name='FileLeafRef' /><Value Type='Text'>.pdf</Value></Contains>
                <Contains><FieldRef Name='FileDirRef'/><Value Type='Lookup'>FolderName</Value></Contains>   
            </And>
        </Where>
    </Query>
</View>
```

**Output**:

[image]

---

**OR** use KQL query like:

```
Path:"https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/siteName/LibraryName/FolderName" filetype:pdf
```

**OR**

```
Path:"https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/siteName/LibraryName/FolderName" filetype:pdf IsDocument:true
```

**Output**:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Ganesh - that solution worked great!

Comment: Great, glad it worked for you! Keep using this forum for asking any questions related to SharePoint.